# HTML/CSS/Java -- Attempting to display:none a page element under a custom theme

Tags: html, css

I wouldn't be asking this, but I have really no other options as I can't get this to work at all and the tech support isn't helping either! I'm sure this is a really simple thing I'm missing here.

I made a website on Wikispaces.com and decided to also make it a portfolio website on the side since I'm paying for one service already, so in the custom themes section of the website I obscured all the editing/wiki stuff from people who are not members of Wikispaces.com using their theme. **I was able to remove just about everything except the Join bar which is driving me up a wall.**

The code in question.

```
<body>...
/*-------- Code in question--------*/
   <WikiIsNotSpaceMember>
      .rbMain .rbC .contentBox .innerContentBox .MenuBar .PageTitle {display:none;}
      .rbMain .rbC .contentBox .innerContentBox .MenuBar .Star {display:none;}
      .rbMain .rbC .contentBox .innerContentBox .MenuBar .ButtonPosition .Buttons.MoreMenuActive .Button.tipme.ButtonMiddle {display:none;}
      .rbMain .rbC .contentBox .innerContentBox .MenuBar .ButtonPosition .Buttons.MoreMenuActive .Button.tipme.ButtonMiddle {display:none;}
      .rbMain .rbC .contentBox .innerContentBox .MenuBar .ButtonPosition {display:none;}
      </WikiIsNotSpaceMember>
```

I used this to remove all the UI elements on Wikispaces for non members using their not-so-often-updated list of custom codes they have on the website's help page and their tech support refused to help me because they don't know how to remove it.
The problem is that I'm completely dense when it comes to HTML/CSS and essentially 0 experience at web development. I've only worked in Java/Processing/MEL mostly as a hobby.

I was using Chrome's Inspect Element to do this... but for some reason anything I try doesn't work here regarding the banner.

**Image of Elements on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4rV2.jpg**

Like I said I'm very unfamiliar with the language and I vaguely understand the difference between a class and a div id. **I want to remove the biege bar located under div id="WikispacesBanner" class="BannerDisplayed" and the associated text asking people to JOIN NOW.** Tried combination of .BannerDisplayed .WikispacesBanner .WikispacesWrapper all to no avail for about a solid hour now.

Thank you!

```
**Edit: Question Answered!**

<WikiIsNotSpaceMember>
    #WikispacesBanner.BannerDisplayed {
        display: none !important;
    }
</WikiIsNotSpaceMember>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#WikispacesBanner.BannerDisplayed {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much I knew it was a dumb question to begin with!

Comment: @Florija why did you choose to use important?

Comment: The important attribute shows that this CSS rule should overwrite all previous ones, clearing the display: block away.

Comment: @Florija yes i understand.. but why didn't `#WikispacesWrapper #WikispaceaBanner.BannerDisplayed` work? why did the CSS cascade priority didnt work here? Looking at http://i.imgur.com/IWVPtQN.jpg i dont see any reasons to use important? mind teaching me?

Comment: Because those css styles were declared before the display: block, making it less important for the CSS parser

Comment: @Florija there is a good example of what i mean in the CSS in question itself.
the rule`#WikispacesWrapper {display: none;}` was being overwritten by `#WikispacesBanner.BannerDisplayed{display: none;}`  Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dqkjb/  I have purposely written the longer selector before the shorter one, but it overrides.. I am not complaining why he chose your answer but just wanted to the reason why my answer didn't work :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26785/discussion-between-florija-and-lucky-soni)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#WikispacesWrapper #WikispacesBanner.BannerDisplayed{
   display: none; 
}
```